# How to determine which Chrome extension is re-directing me to ad sites

Tags: malware, windows, web-browser, browser-extensions

Twice now, seemingly randomly, I've been redirected to an ad site.

I believe it has occurred both times when I have a new tab open, type what I'm searching for (Google is my default search engine), press enter and then end up on the ad page.

As these links could be malicious, I'd advise against visiting them without proper sandboxing/virtualization, but I'll share them in case it helps identify what the cause could be.

The most recent time the URL was this:

```
http://namtofe.com/r2.php?e=Q4NW4efEyAwmioHKz%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
```

which redirected me to

```
https://www.mamma.com/extensions/?subid=529493018&cpv=0.020&utm_source=dsn&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=launch&sid=202312290718523484ec0c1324aea708
```

Looking at my history, the first time this happened to me, the URL was this:

```
http://namtofe.com/r2.php?e=1DXwhfAHJdlpfIWR2E6i%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
```

(not positive what it redirected to looking at my history.)

Technically I don't know that this is caused by a Chrome Extension, though I can't think of any Windows applications that I've installed that would be a likely cause of this. Most are widely used applications, tools used by businesses, small open source tools, or things I'm developing or modifying myself. Furthermore, if a desktop application were to open a malicious link, I imagine it'd do it in a new window, not in the currently active tab.

Likewise, if my router were hacked, that could possibly explain this, but I've never encountered this issue on any other devices: only on this single laptop.

Here are the Chrome extensions that I use:

- Ad Accelerator (speeds up YouTube ads, is open source)
- Application Launcher For Drive (by Google)
- Bitwarden (open source password manager)
- Fluff Busting Purity (cleans up Facebook)
- Google Docs Offline (by Google)
- Less Distracting Reddit (open source)
- Media Bias Fact Check - shows https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/ ratings on different sites
- Netflix Party is now Teleparty (watch Netflix, Youtube, Disney Plus, Hulu, HBO, and Amazon Prime Video in sync with friends)
- Return YouTube Dislike (shows estimation of number of dislikes, plus allows you to contribute to data by clicking the dislike button it adds)
- SingleFile (downloads a page as a single .html file)
- SponsorBlock for YouTube (skips over sponsored sections)
- uBlock Origin (open source ad blocker)
- Unhook - Remove YouTube recommended videos
- Video Speed Controller
- Webtime Tracker (keeps track of how much time I spend on different sites — doesn't require Internet access)

The permissions section for most of these extensions show that they can only modify data on specific domains, in addition to being able to read all browser history. However, from what I can tell, any Chrome extension can open new windows or redirect you to a different URL. Is there any way to determine which extension is doing so?

Since this occurs so infrequently, I'm not sure disabling and re-enabling Chrome extensions one extension at a time is a feasible plan. I suppose I only *need* a couple of these extensions, but I find them helpful for wasting less time on the Internet and staying more productive.

I understand that having 15 different extensions potentially presents a security risk, though I think the same could be said for installing any desktop application (unless properly sandboxed or virtualized, which is not made convenient in Windows, which I unfortunately need for work since certain performance sensitive applications don't work in Wine/Proton/etc.)

With my currently open browser tabs, the only extensions I see running in Chrome Task Manager are the following:

- Bitwarden
- Netflix Party
- SingleFile
- uBlock Origin
- Unhook
- Webtime Tracker

However, I suppose it's possible that extensions can have service workers that periodically will run but otherwise will not show up most of the time here (not sure.)

I tried searching for `namtofe` (the spam domain I was redirected to) in `...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` in my IDE, but could not find it. Considering the URL was different both times, this isn't too surprising, as the extension likely fetched content from a different URL to see what URL the user should be redirected to.

Anyone have any tips? I'd like to remove and report whichever extension is causing this.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Simply put: read the permissions they have and then just turn them off one by one till you find the culprit. Also your DNS server might be set to a malicous one

Comment: @SirMuffington From what I can tell, all Chrome extensions have permission to open new tabs and redirect, and it's impossible to disable that functionality. You can enable/disable certain functionality, such as webcam, mic, and even sound usage, but there are also permissions that can't be disabled (JavaScript, images, automatic downloads, etc.)

Comment: @SirMuffington I checked my network settings in Windows and they seem to be set to the default (not set to a custom DNS; they automatically obtain an IP address.) Running `ipconfig/all` in cmd and the DNS servers seem to be correct for my ISP. Thanks for the tip though, that is a good thing to check. Since it doesn't appear that malware has changed my DNS server to something malicious, this does make me more confident that it's a Chrome extension causing the redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Zip the entire add-ons folder, upload it to virustotal.com

Hopefully some AV solutions know your malware.

If that doesn't work, I'd disable all add-ons which don't have well known developers/companies behind them.

Lastly there's a non-zero chance it's not one of your add-ons but some malware running on your PC.

Comment: I zipped the entire extensions folder and uploaded it to virustotal.com, but it didn't find anything. Thank you for the tip though, I'll use that resource for the future if I suspect a program or extension is malicious.

Comment: "Lastly there's a non-zero chance it's not one of your add-ons but some malware running on your PC. " 



— I understand that, but from a developer standpoint, it's a lot simpler to just open a link in a new window of the default browser rather than redirecting the current tab to a malicious site. And considering this is just visiting a website (as opposed to a stealthy virus that steals my info, or ransomware), it seems unlikely that malware of this complexity is present. Windows Defender didn't find anything in a quick scan, though I can run a full scan later.